# sitemap hierarchy levels

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap

I am trying to make site map of my website. I have hireachy of 4 levels.

Now the top level sitemap will be an index sitemap xml file, containing path of lower level site map file. The last level sitemap will be a urlset sitemap xml file, containing the urls of the website pages.

What about the second level and third level sitemap, should they be index sitemaps or urlset sitemaps?